# Data type assertion fail in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use discrete Fourier transform (dft) and using [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html)

I am using a gray scale image(8UC1) and when I run the program the following error appears on the screen :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (DataType<_Tp>::channels == m.channels()) in cv:: Mat_<float>::operator =
```

and breaks at the following line

```
Mat planes[] = { Mat_<float>(padded), Mat::zeros(padded.size(), CV_32F) };
```

Comment: can you show us, how you construct 'padded' ? (that must be a float type image already. you're probably missing a conversion on the way)

Comment: @berak I am using as it is the code which is there in this link http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

Comment: sorry, i was on the wrong track. the err is about channels, not type, also `Mat_<float>(padded)` does an internal conversion alrady. so - no idea now.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I was playing around with the samples and came across this too.